# See stats of data in and out of each connection to a port

Tags: networking, netstat, conntrack

I have an application listening to a port. The clients connect to it using http connection. At any given time I see around 3000 connections established. I assume not all these connections are in use (sending and receiving data) in parallel. To ensure this I want to see some statistics.

Q. How many connections in parallel do send or receive data.

I see the connections are closed in some interval and new connections open up.

Comment: If they're in the Established state then they are in use whether data is flowing or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you using linux , you can set number of maximum connection via :

```
sysctl net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max=YOURNUMBER
```

Of course , may be you need to load `ip_conntrack` module

Answer (score 0):

We can use many tools (netstat, ip, /proc, etc.). 
The ss utility may give you a very useful info:

```
ss -i -4 -t -o state established
```

In this example, we obtain internal data of connections established tcp/ipv4.